# Can I use the Raspberry Pi as a second monitor?

Tags: xorg

I have a desktop running Ubuntu 10.04 (which I should upgrade - I know!), which uses GDM. It currently has 2 screens installed, which are configured using `xorg.conf`. It includes using `xinerama` to act as one large display.

Is it possible to use an Xserver on the RPi as another display in this configuration? I'm happy to use any RPi distribution, but Arch is currently installed. To clarify, I want to extended my computer's desktop across the Pi.

Answer (score 10):

I am doing this right now, however not using `xorg` configuration, as I hate editing that horrible file. 
Using this method requires the Pi to be plugged into the second monitor and works by sending your mouse and keystrokes over SSH to the Pi's xsession.
This may not be what you want. However, it is **much easier**.

This is achieved by using `x2x`, which can be installed and set up *very* easily.

#### Install `x2x` on both devices:

```
sudo pacman -S x2x
```

#### Configure SSH:

On the Raspberry Pi edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add/uncomment the following line:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

and restart `sshd` using

```
sudo /etc/rc.d/sshd restart
```

#### SSH to the Pi from your other device and run `x2x`:

```
ssh -X 192.168.0.70 'x2x -east -to :0'
```

Replace the IP with the address of your Raspberry Pi.

Now you should be able to move your mouse between the two X sessions.

Comment: Synergy can be installed to accomplish something very similar.

Comment: Synergy just moves the mouse and keyboard, right? You still run programs on the Pi. I just want to use it as a display.

Comment: I get an error
No protocol specified
x2x - error: can not open display :0

Comment: I've got it working! And you're quite right, it's not what I want...

Comment: I'm interested in doing domething similar. What is not working?

Comment: This is why I said Synergy can be installed to accomplish something similar =).

Comment: You could probably get the RPI to connect to your remote Xserver, which will allow you to run remote programs from your RPI, but getting windows to move across the display is much more difficult and largely impossible.

Comment: Does this still working?

Answer (score 2):

With a little hacking, you might be able to pull it off.
What you'll need to do is set of a "fake" display and then use VNC to connect to that display.

This would basically be replicating what zonescreen does.
http://www.zoneos.com/zonescreen.htm