# How to control pi HDMI output from laptop via VNC

Tags: ssh, hdmi, remote, vnc, output

I have my pi plugged into a monitor with HDMI, and I want to use my laptop (running Ubuntu Linux) to control what it displays on the monitor through VNC. Currently, I can connect to the pi with VNC, but what I see in my laptop's VNC window isn't displayed on the monitor - instead, I just see the pi's command prompt. I want the image of the pi's desktop that I see on my laptop to display on the monitor, and I want to be able to control it with my laptop's mouse and keyboard - in short, I want the pi to mirror the VNC client. I'm using Remmina on the client laptop but if there's a better program let me know. In your response, please lay out all the steps and be as painfully specific as you can be - I'm a newcomer to all this.

<del>A similar question to mine was asked [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/controlling-the-hdmi-output-via-ssh), but I found the answers unclear.</del>

Comment: If you know of a similar question where you "found the answers unclear", you should **explain what you find unclear**.  Go through it *in detail*. Otherwise you are putting the onus on others to guess what it is you don't get -- in which case they either will not bother to reply (since you haven't bothered to make a corresponding effort) or else they may explain things in a way which is equally unclear.  Q&A's are a two-way street...you can ask a thoughtful question and get a thoughtful answer...or you can just be lazy in hopes someone will do all the work for you...

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for the advice. This was my first post here and I'm still learning the etiquette. I should have been more specific.

Comment: Alright.  Thanks for not taking that the wrong way ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install x11vnc and configure it to get same screen on HDMI and VNC client.  See this answer https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9610/8697

There are some caveats related to screen size. Also, I believe, you don't get the hardware acceleration, but you don't get this with normal VNC.

You could also install `x2x` on both devices, but I have never tried this myself.

Answer (score 0):

You have VNC working, but the output isn't displayed on the monitor. I believe you need to either boot to desktop (options in `raspi-config`) or on the command prompt run `startx`. After this, you then connect via VNC and you should be able to do what you are asking.