# Connect on Raspberrypi:0

Tags: vnc

I noticed I cannot start VNCserver at :0 because it is occupied, so I think this is what I get to see if I connect a HDMI cable, right?

So can I connect to exactly this session and not to a new one (which does not have my preferred icon layout etc.)?

Also if I open multiple VNC Servers, will this take much RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot (easily) share an existing screen See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28374/8697

You have not told us anything - what system/software are you using; what is the exact error; how have you set up VNC. Unless you do no one can help.

You should try to search this site for `VNC` to find existing answers.

PS You are not running "N00b"; I assume you have installed Raspbian.

Comment: I guess this user means not that particular software but that his/her experience with linux is of level 'noob'.