# Raspberry pi as a second monitor for Windows

Tags: raspbian, windows

I have a model B raspberry pi running raspbian and a laptop running Windows 7. Is there software that I can install to use the raspberry pi monitor as a second screen for my laptop. For example I want to open Excel on one monitor and Matlab on another.

I am aware of [Can I use the Raspberry Pi as a second monitor?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/909/can-i-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-second-monitor). This is for Ubuntu, I want to do the same with Windows 7.

Comment: The doubt it. The only way that that works is because both are Linux and both have an X-server. Windows has neither. l you really want to do this, I think you should try out Ubuntu.

Comment: That is possible on Linux because of how Linux allows multiple screens to run in the Kernel level, and allowing another X applciation to connect to that scream over a TCP pipe. In Windows this is only possible via the Graphcis Driver level, which means if you want another monitor you should have a GFX card that supports 2,3,4+ screens. You can cast your screen with clever software but it is very laggy.

Comment: [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) lets you move the cursor from one system to another, across platforms. Not really what you want but it deserves to be mentioned. Fairly easy to set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get this to work with rPlay by VMlite on the raspberry and using Airparrot on your Windows Computer. rPlay can mimic the Airplay Mirroring feature (like a Apple TV or even Chromecast?) to extend your Desktop

Performance can be pretty good if you have a good network, but may not be suited to your needs.

rPlay:
http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&Itemid=158&func=view&catid=23&id=10991

AirParrot:
http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/

Answer (score 0):

To view an linux application on a Windows machine You will need to install an Xserver. These will allow you to run a linux application and have the results displayed within a window on the your Windows 7 laptop.  The application is actually still running on the Linux box. There are several free packages for this. Try [VcXsrv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/)‎ as it is compiled from xorg sources so you know it will be compatible.

I expect you will also need to use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to log into to your Raspberry pi and make it easy to remote the window to the Windows 7 machine.

To get it to work:

1. configure PuTTY to do X11 forwarding (tick box)
2. connect to the Rasberry pi using PuTTY (you will need to know the Rasberry pi's IP number)
3. once connected try something like:
4. *midori &*
   This will run the midori web browser,  the & disconnects the program from the PuTTY window and will appear in it's own windows on the Windows 7 laptop.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. If you could include the important info from the link it would make your answer more useful and help keep this site/Q:A more useful in the future, as including this info protects against link rot.

Comment: This isn't responsive to the question. The question was about using a RPi in a manner similar to an additional monitor on a Windows computer. It is not about viewing Linus apps on Windows machines.