# x2x on Raspbian

Tags: xorg

Hello everybody!

I'm trying to setup my raspberry pi as a second monitor (to something like [synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) ) with my Debian laptop using x2x and I am unable to figure out what is going on. I tried following instructions from [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/909/can-i-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-second-monitor), but I keep getting 
 `x2x - error: can not open display :1.0`
and other related problems.

Here are the links / guides I tried to follow:
First answer here: [Can I use the Raspberry Pi as a second monitor?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/909/can-i-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-second-monitor/910#910)
Second answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/71794/extend-linux-desktop-to-another-x-windows-display/221391#221391) 
Last answer [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/24394-x2x-configuration.html#4) 

Other than that, I'm stuck with my error messages. Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

After a few quirks here and there, I managed to make the setup work magically. So what I ended up doing is rebooting my laptop and Rpi by running
`ssh -X IPADDR "x2x -to :0 -east"`
on my laptop. (with `IPADDR` being my Pi's IP address)

Just make sure that on both the Pi and the remote computer have the `$DISPLAY` set to `:0` not `localhost:0` or anything else. This can be checked with `echo $DISPLAY`.